`springdoc-openapi-starter` swagger-ui/index.html page error 404 - not found
I am trying to integrate the springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.6.0 into my Spring Boot 3 app. Currently for some strange reason /v3/api-docs is working properly, but the UI does not work, console is printing that swagger-ui/index.html is not found (404). Any idea what can cause this?
I tried removing all interceptors and keep security config on minimal settings permitting all on swagger endpoints.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
